# How does Empirical Bayesian Kriging of ArcGIS Pro handle sampling bias?

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation, kriging, sampling, geostatistical-analyst

In ArcGIS Pro, simple kriging approaches allow you to de-cluster your data before applying a normal-score transformation. According to the Esri guideline, normal-score transformations are only feasible if the input data does not exhibit a strong sampling bias.

[Empirical Bayesian Kriging](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/what-is-empirical-bayesian-kriging-.htm) does allow you to apply a normal-score transformation to the data before interpolation, but does not allow you to (at least manually) apply de-clustering algorithms on the data. Following that logic, EBK must either apply some sort of de-clustering technique automatically or must otherwise be suited to properly produce a prediction surface from geographically biased input data. Neither the Esri guidelines/publications nor other sources provide any information on this.

How then does EBK handle sampling bias?

Comment: I'm asking in the Ten Fold chat room of Cross Validated whether they may have an approach to getting this question answered.

Comment: Thinking it's the latter - that EBK is distribution-free, assuming what you got 'empirical' is what there is, rather than relying on any assumption of the distribution of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but I pulled this extract from my university course notes from a while back:

EBK is a form of kriging that attempts to account for sampling bias by estimating the local mean and variance at each point, rather than assuming a global mean and variance as in ordinary kriging. This allows EBK to produce more accurate predictions in situations where the data exhibits non-uniformity or heterogeneity.

One way that EBK can handle sampling bias is by using an adaptive binning technique, which divides the data into small, non-overlapping regions, or bins. The algorithm then estimates the mean and variance for each bin and uses this information to produce predictions. This can help to reduce the effect of sampling bias by allowing the algorithm to adjust the predictions based on the local characteristics of the data.

ArcGIS Pro allows you to define the "bin size" parameter. This parameter controls the size of the bins that are used to divide the data into smaller regions. By reducing the bin size, you can ensure that the algorithm is using a larger number of smaller regions to estimate the local mean and variance, which can help to reduce the effect of sampling bias.

Another technique that EBK may use to handle sampling bias is by estimating the mean and variance of the data in a way that takes into account the spatial distribution of the data. The algorithm does this by fitting a spatial trend surface to the data, and then using this surface to estimate the local mean and variance at each point. This can help to adjust for any systematic biases that may be present in the data.

It's also worth noting that in practice, EBK like any other interpolation methods are heuristic, which means that they are based on certain assumptions, these assumptions may not be met and the results can be affected by sampling bias, as you stated that esri guidelines do not provide any information on it, I would recommend validating the results by comparing them with external data, if possible, or by cross-validating the predictions using a subset of the data.